# Add a value to a key in a hashmap if it satisfies a condition

Tags: java, hashmap

Let us say I have a HashMap that stores a `Fruit` as its key and an ArrayList of `Cars` as its value.

A `Fruit` is an Object with a `String name, int height, int width`. A `Car` is an object with a `String name, String FruitItRunsOver, int weight`.

I am supposed to add Fruits and Cars that run over this Fruit into my HashMap. I am initially given Fruits sequentially and then I am given Cars sequentially.

Now, the problem I am having is that I know which fruit a Car runs over by the  FruitItRunsOver member variable which, as you can probably guess, will be the same as the name of a Fruit. Initially, I am given the Fruits, and as I am given them, I `put(Fruit, new ArrayList<Car>())`.

However, once I get to the cars, I am wondering what is the best way to add them? I am tempted to have something that looks like this:

```
for (Fruit f : hashmap.keySet()) {
    if (f.getName().equals(car.getFruit())) {
        ArrayList<Car> cars = hashmap.get(f);
        cars.add(car);
        hashmap.put(f, cars)
    }
}
```

.. But I think that looks egregious. I was thinking I could have the keys, instead of being the Fruits, be the fruit names. But keep in mind I need to have the other member variables of the fruit saved. I will need them later on in the code. So, what, I should have a nested HashMap? If so, how should the structure look like?

Thanks

Edit: I suppose this is my fault for not clarifying. `car.getFruit()` will return the fruit name `FruitItRunsOver`, not a `Fruit` object.

Comment: Having Map<Key,Collection<Value>> is not something uncommon

Comment: @Antoniossss can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your approach, exactly?

Comment: Multimap: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: @JoeC Well, there is nothing WRONG, per se. But I am asking if there is something better. A better practice. Because I do not think I am doing something optimal

Comment: @JohnLexus its what JoeC asked you - there is nothing wrong with having such data structure as Map of key-collections. You could ommit that additional map by creating relations so Fruid could have `Car carrier` insteed of plain name, and Car could have `List<Fruit> fruits` - this is would you would normally do on database level and later on reflected that in data model.

Comment: I think a question like this would fit better on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  But please review their Help Centre before posting.

Comment: @Antoniossss Oh, okay. No, I am not saying there is anything wrong with that implementation. I am saying I am disatisfied with precisely how I am searching for the right Fruit.

Comment: You shouldn't do `hashmap.put(f, cars)` while iterating over the map's key set, but that statement doesn't actually do anything anyway. Those three statements could just be `hashmap.get(f).add(car);`.

Comment: @Radiodef how should I update a  KV pair while iterating, then?

Comment: You can iterate over the `entrySet`, you could use `replaceAll` or you could iterate over a copy of the map, but in this case you don't need to do anything except add the car to the list. Adding the car to the list already adds it to the list in the map.

Comment: If your map has already all the possible fruits you can use only `computeIfPresent`, if it doesn't you can use both.

Comment: @JoseDaSilva Yes, it will have all the possible fruits.

Answer (score 2):

For each Car you add, you iterate on fruits, it is not efficient and in a some way counter intuitive as you have a `Map` that provides a direct access by key.

It would be more efficient to use as key the same value that the car has as field to represent a fruit. Use the String `FruitItRunsOver`  if it is suitable

```
Map<String, List<Car>> carsByFruitName = new HashMap<>();
// populate the map with Fruit name and empty ArrayList
..

// for each car to create, retrieve the List of Car from the String name representing the fruit 
List<Car> cars = carsByFruitName.get(car.getFruitItRunsOver());
cars.add(car);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a `Map<String,Fruit>` to map fruit names to `Fruit` objects. This map could be temporary if you plan no further modifications to the fruit-to-cars map, or you could keep it for the duration of the program's run:

```
Map<String,Fruit> fruitByName = new HashMap<>();
for (Fruit fruit : allFruits) {
    fruitByName.put(fruit.getName(), fruit);
}
Map<Fruit,List<Car>> carByFruit = new HashMap<>();
for (Car car : allCars) {
    Fruit f = fruitByName.get(car.getFruit());
    if (f == null) {
        ... // Throw an exception
    }
    List<Car> cars = carByFruit.get(f);
    if (cars == null) {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        carByFruit.put(f, cars);
    }
    cars.add(car);
}
```

You could also make a `Map<String,FruitAndItsCars>`, with an additional `FruitAndItsCars` class to combine a `Fruit` object with a `List<Car>` object list.

Comment: In Java 8+, you can replace the get/if/add with `carByFruit.computeIfAbsent(f, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(car)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Would the new ArrayList<>() get rid of the previous values?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you! I've been out of Java programming for over a decade, so I keep forgetting new tricks.

Comment: @JohnLexus no: it only evaluates that when there is no existing value for that key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

The method `computeIfAbsent` receives as first argument the key and as second argument a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) (function of one argument). This function receives the key and is executed only when the key is not present, then it should return the value. In this case an empty list of cars the when the key does not exist, and the current list of cars when it does exist. Then the new car is added.

```
Fruit carFruit = getFruitByName(car.getFruit());
hashmap.computeIfAbsent(carFruit, (fruit) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(car);
```

This way you don't need a for loop, and you are already handling the case when the key does not exists, adding the new list.

To obtain the fruit by name, if you you only have a collection of Fruits you can create the map with java's stream, this map has a string with the name as key and the Fruit itseld as the value:

```
Map<String, Fruit> fruitByName = getFruits() // however that you get all the fruits 
                                             // e.g. hashmap.keySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Fruit::getName, Function.identity()));
```

Having this map `Map<String, Fruit>`, you could replace the method `getFruitByName()` with a simple call to fruitByName.get(fruitName).

note: you normally should have the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods defined to use a object as key, the `Fruit` in this case.

Edit:
Using sugestion of Andy Turner

Comment: I would love to get a more thorough description of ho to use computeIfabsent/present. I dont get how to use it

Comment: Ok a will add a brieve explanation

Comment: Thank you! Also, what do you mean by "equals" and "hashcode" methods? I mean I know what a method is, but what do you mean I should have them defined?

Comment: You're overcomplicating this by using both `computeIfPresent` and `computeIfAbsent`: `computeIfAbsent` returns the value, so you can just use `hashmap.computeIfAbsent(car.getFruit(), f -> new ArrayList<>()).add(car)`.

Comment: "note2: if your map already has all possible fruits added " then you can just use `get`. There's no need for the lambda in that case.

Comment: @AndyTurner about the complicating things, no. If i use the returned value, i could get 1st a np exception and second duplicated values added to the list.

Comment: @JoseDaSilva 1) only if you're adding null values to the map elsewhere, in which case you'd get a NPE with your code too 2) how, exactly?

Comment: @AndyTurner 1) the key is not defined, so `computeIfPresent` doesn't do anything just return null, then i add -> np. 2) the is already present, and the car was added with `computeIfPresent` then `computeIfAbsent` will return the value (the list), then i add again -> duplicated. So it should stay how is now.

Comment: @JoseDaSilva 1) I didn't say to use `computeIfPresent`. 2) I didn't say to use `computeIfPresent`. Aside from anything, if you're invoking `computeIfPresent` and `computeIfAbsent`, you could just use `compute`, except that it's more cleanly expressed using `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes you're right. I misread (though you were suggesting add() in both not just absent). Fixed.